# How to find the first property that is an array in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm creating a function that loops through an array like this:

```
schema: [{
  name: 'firstRow',
  fields: [{
    name: 'name',
    text: 'Name',
    type: 'text',
    col: 12,
    value: ''
  }]
}, {
```

And returns a callback with the values of the objects:

```
eachDeep (array, callback) {
  array.forEach(item => {
    item.fields.forEach(field => {
      callback(field)
    })
  })
},
```

As you can see the `item.fields.forEach` part is harcoded. How can I modify the function so it detects the first property that it's an array and loop through it? (e.g. in this case that property is `fields`).

Comment: `schema` is an object?

Comment: @MikeTung No it's an array.

Comment: do you mean `schema = [blah blah blah]`?

Comment: @MikeTung Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Can't you just retrieve it with `item[0]`?

Comment: What do you mean by _"so it detects the first property that it's an array"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var big_array = 
[
  {
    name: 'firstRow',
    fields: [{
      name: 'name',
      text: 'Name',
      type: 'text',
      col: 12,
      value: ''
    }]
  }
];
  
for (let item of big_array)
{
  for (let key in item)
  {
    if (Array.isArray(item[key]) )
    {
      console.log('this is an array do something:', key);
    }
  }
}
```

You could check using `Array.isArray()`

Comment: this won't work if he has multiple properties that are arrays... how would he know what is the first?

Comment: Then break or have a variable that let's him know. E.g. `found = false` when he finds the first array then `found = true` and stop using it or w/e. The question is missing a bit for me to properly handle it so I'm just generalising for the moment.

Comment: @MikeTung What do you mean by "the first" within an object?

Comment: @guest271314 which is really my point, which is why I kept it general. No idea if OP wants to find the first via ordered keys or whatever just so happens to come first. Or if he's being vague and just wants to find any Array in general.

Comment: Is there an order associated with `javascript` plain object properties?

Comment: @guest271314 No, but you can do `Object.keys(blah).sort()` and get it ordered.

Comment: @A.Lau What does OP mean by _"so it detects the first property that it's an array"_?

Comment: @guest271314 no idea, that's why I just kept it general for him to work it out.

Answer (score 3):

To find whether a property of an object is an array or not you can also use this one:

```
//let item be your object's property
if(typeof item == "object" && item.length > 0){
    //do whatever if it is an array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the field is not an array or not, if so loop it, otherwise do something else with it.

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'firstRow',
  fields: [{
    name: 'name',
    text: 'Name',
    type: 'text',
    col: 12,
    value: ''
  }]
}, {
  name: 'firstRow',
  fields: [{
    name: 'name',
    text: 'Name',
    type: 'text',
    col: 12,
    value: ''
  }]
}];


eachDeep (array, callback) {
  array.forEach(item => {
    // loop through each property again
    item.forEach(prop => {
      // if property is an array
      if (prop instanceof Array) {
         prop.forEach(field => callback(field));
      } else {
         // property is not an array
         // do something else
      }
    })
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to find the first array property you can do the following. Using ES6.

```
const schema = [{
               name: 'firstRow',
               fields: [{
                         name: 'name',
                         text: 'Name',
                         type: 'text',
                         col: 12,
                         value: ''
                      }]
               }]

let firstArr;
schema.forEach(item => {
  firstArr = Object.keys(item).filter(k => Array.isArray(item[k]))[0];
})
```